# How does placement new know which layout to create?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, placement-new

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
struct A { int a; };
struct B : virtual A { int b; };
struct C : virtual A  { int c; };
struct D : B,C { int d; };
int main()
{
  D complete;
  B contiguous;
  B & separate = complete;
  B * p[2] = {&separate, &contiguous};
  // two possible layouts for B: 
  std::cout<< (int)((char*)(void*) &p[0]->a -(char*)(void*)&p[0]->b)<<" "<< sizeof(*p[0])<< "\n";
  std::cout<< (int)((char*)(void*) &p[1]->a -(char*)(void*)&p[1]->b)<<" "<< sizeof(*p[1])<< "\n";

  alignas(B) char buff[sizeof(B)];
  void * storage = static_cast<void*>(buff);
  // new expression skips allocation function:
  auto pointer= new (storage) B;        // Which layout to create?
  std::cout << typeid(pointer).name()<<"\n"; 
  pointer->~B();    // Destructor knows layout through typed pointer.
}
// sample output (Debian 8, amd64):
// 24 16
// 4 16
// P1B
```

Is there a section in the *C++14 standard* that reqires 'new' to create a particular layout? Is there guarantee that
the layout created by new fits into a buffer of size sizeof(B) and with offset zero?

---

edit: Could you please use grep-friendly terminology or provide references? I added a reference to the standard to the question.

Take into consideration the sample output above: What does the number 24 tell you? What is the size of the buffer?

There might be a statement in the standard that a most derived object is always a straightforward, contiguous copy of the object representation,
but I haven't found this one.

The thing we know about new is that it shall be used with a complete object type. [expr.new]

There is an example for a new-expression with the placement option in [class.dtor] §12.4 (14). However, the example might work simply because the class therein is standard-layout.

Answer (score 2):

> *Where is the guarantee that the layout created by new fits into a buffer of size sizeof(B) and with offset zero*

From the the type being named in `new` as its argument being `B`. A `B` is being made, not an `D`. The type `B` "knows nothing" about `D`.  The declaration of `D` has no influence on `B`; the `B` declaration can be put into translation units in which `D` doesn't appear, yet everywhere in the program there will be agreement about the size of `B` and is layout, regardless of whether `D` is also known in those places or not.

A C++ object of type `T` has a size `sizeof T`. This means that it fits into `sizeof T` bytes; it cannot be the case that `(sizeof T) + k` bytes are required for its representation, where `k > 0`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `k != 0`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke  If `k` is `signed int` and negative, what happens when it's added to a `size_t`? :)

Comment: I'm not sure... You tell me. But I think that's probably why I say it should be `k != 0` and not `k > 0`. You wrote the answer...

Comment: @AlexsWilke Note that it can be the case that fewer than `sizeof T` bytes are actually required for the representation of a type `T` due to padding.

Comment: 'buffer' implies 'sequence of contiguous bytes', while the object might not be contiguous and for _this_ reason not fit into the buffer. I know this is not a size issue. If you know the standard makes a guarantee, provide references, please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to create what you call a "separate" layout, other than creating a derived type, and fishing `B` out of it.

"Layout of `B` as portion of its derived class" is not the same as "Layout of `B`". Placement `new` and regular `new` use the layout based on the type itself, with is the default, stand-alone layout.

> Where is the guarantee that the layout created by new fits into a buffer of size `sizeof(B)`?

`sizeof(B)` returns the size of `B` itself, not `B`-as-part-of-some-other-class. That is all the space needed to store a stand-alone `B`, regardless of the way that you allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening in a new expression:

1. Allocating memory for a type by calling operator new (which is no
   new expression)
2. Construction of the desired type.

Usually the operator new can utilize the size, which is passed by the compiler inside the new expression. Having a placement new (offering storage), the programmer is responsible to provide a storage large enough to hold the desired type.

Anyway: Do not mix allocation and object construction. These are two distinct tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a precision: a way to implement virtual inheritance is to push (all) the virtual base classes at the end of the classes after all the own member fields declarations. Here should be the organization of class D and class B.

```
class D:
   -----
     pvmt for B, D (include shift to find A)
     int b;
   -----
     pvmt for C (include shift to find A)
     int c;
   -----
     int a;
   -----

class B:
   -----
     pvmt for B (include shift to find A)
     int b;
   -----
     int a;
   -----

class C:
   -----
     pvmt for C (include shift to find A)
     int c;
   -----
     int a;
   -----
```

It is not `new` that chooses the layout for `void* rawObject= new (storage) B;`; It is the fact that you create a concrete B object. So the layout is the same than the one for `contiguous` - the second one.